# I want to add google plus badge into my html template but its not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

i try many things from google developers site but result is same.
HERE Is the code:

```
    <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="24" data-href="https://plus.google.com/107623689080156420982" data-rel="publisher">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Working.. http://jsbin.com/vacoqedeku/edit?html,js,output, any errors in the `console`? Do you have a public URL of your site?

Comment: worked!!! thanks bro....

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck..